# Moving files with Wildcards in Python

Tags: windows, file, python-2.7, wildcard

So I am trying to move say all files starting with "A" to a certain directory. Now I now Windows command prompt does not support this method:

```
move A* A_Dir
```

But could this combined with Python find a way? Or am I gonna have to go through each individual file? 
Such as:

```
contents=os.listdir('.')
for file in content:
    if file[0] == 'A':
        os.system("move %s A_Dir" % file)
```

... etc. Is there any other solution that is more simpler and quicker? 
-Thanks!

Comment: If you're doing this on windows use a batch file command, it's perfect for that.

Comment: What would that batch file look like?

Answer (score 4):

**On Windows:** This example moves files starting with "A" from "C:\11" to "C:\2"

**Option #1:** if you are using batch file, create batch file (movefiles.bat) as show below:

**movefiles.bat:**

```
move /-y "C:\11\A*.txt" "C:\2\"
```

Execute this batch file from python script as shown below:

```
import os
batchfile = "C:\\1\\movefiles.bat"
os.system( "%s" % batchfile)
```

[image: move command]

**Option #2:** **using glob & shutil**

```
import glob
import shutil
for data in glob.glob("C:\\11\\A*.txt"):
    shutil.move(data,"C:\\2\\")
```

If we want to `move` all `files` and `directory` starting with A:

```
import glob
import shutil

for data in glob.glob("C:\\11\\A*"):
        shutil.move(data,"C:\\2\\")
```

Based on @eryksun comment, I have added `if not os.path.isdir(data):`, if only `files` starting with A are required to be moved and in this case, directory will be ignored.

```
import glob
import shutil
import os
for data in glob.glob("C:\\11\\A*"):
    if not os.path.isdir(data):
        shutil.move(data,"C:\\2\\")
```

Comment: cmd's built-in `move` command doesn't match multiple directories with wildcards, so `move A* A_Dir` only moves files that match `A*`. For the equivalent in Python you need to filter directories out of the glob, e.g. `[f for f in glob.glob('A*') if not os.path.isdir(f)] `.

Comment: @eryksun - Thanks! Option #2, in the given Answer, makes use of `glob` and `shutil`. do you think, we should update the answer to add `if not os.path.isdir(f)` condition?

Comment: BTW, I believe we need not put `if not os.path.isdir(f)` as Option #2 uses `wild card` `A*.txt`, it will only returns files starting with `A` and having `extension .txt` and directory will be ignored. kindly confirm before I go and update Option #2 in the Answer

Comment: The solution needs to be general. Also, the question asks for `A*`, not `A*.txt`. But even if that weren't the case, there's nothing that says a directory can't be named `A_Dir.txt`.