# sh.mv() does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, sh, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to move certain files to another file in python, using `sh.mv("*.nii", "./zipfile")`. 
As you can see, I want to move all of the files with the ending .nii to the folder zipfile in the same directory. 
zipfile exists and there are files with the ending .nii in the folder. Also, this works when I execute it directly over the shell.
But when I try to execute the python script, I get `/bin/mv: cannot stat '*.nii': No such file or directory`.

Comment: May I suggest you use shutil to do this in junction with glob? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913088/moving-files-with-wildcards-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need to iterate and grab each file individually for that to work. Also I'm a fan of the shutil library:

```
import os, shutil
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".nii"):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join('./zipfile', file))
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I did upvote, but it doesn't show because I don't have enough reputation yet. Shame that it doesn't work with `sh.mv()` like in the shell...